# Save React Component scroll position in Redux on Component update

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I have a React Component using a hook to save the scroll position of the component when the component unmounts. This works great but fails when navigating from one set of data to another set of data without the component unmounting.

For instance, imagine the Slack Interface where there is a sidebar of message channels on the left and on the right is a list of messages (messageList). If you were to navigate between two channels, the messageList component would update with a new set of data for the messageList, but the component was never unmounted so scroll position never gets saved.

I came up with a solution that works, but also throws a warning.

My current useEffect hook for the component (stripped down) and the code that currently saves scroll position whenever the messageList ID changes:

```
// Component...

const usePrevious = (value) => {
    const ref = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        ref.current = value;
    });
    return ref.current;
};

// Save scroll position when Component unmounts
useEffect(() => {    
    return () => {
        setScrollOffset(parent._id, scrollPos.current);
    };
}, []);

// Save scroll position when Parent ID changes
const oldParent = usePrevious(parent);
if (oldParent && parent._id !== oldParent._id) {
    setScrollOffset(oldParent._id, list ? list.scrollTop : 0);
}

// ...Component
```

The error this throws is:
`Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component.`

And the line that is causing it is the setScrollOffset call inside of the last if block. I'm assuming that while this works it is not the way that I should be handling this sort of thing. What is a better way to handle saving scroll position when a specific prop on the component changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestions of [@drew-reese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese), he got me pointed down the right path. After adopting his solution (which previously I could not get working properly), I was able to isolate my problem to usage with react-router. (connected-react-router in my case). The issue was that the component was rendering and firing the onScroll event handler and overwriting my scroll position before I could read it.

For me the solution ended up being to keep my existing useEffect hook but pull the scroll offset save out of it and into useLayoutEffect (Had to keep useEffect since there is other stuff in useEffect that I removed for the sake of keeping the sample code above lean). useLayoutEffect allowed me to read the current scroll position before the component fired the onScroll event which was ultimately overwriting my saved scroll position reference to 0.

This actually made my code much cleaner overall by removing the need for my usePrevious hook entirely. My useLayoutEffect hook now looks like this:

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        setScrollOffset(parent._id, scrollPos.current);
    };
}, [parent._id]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `parent._id` to the dependency array. Refactor your code to still cache the previous parent id, add that to the dependency, and move the conditional test inside the effect.

[Cleaning up an effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect)

> The clean-up function runs before the component is removed from the UI
>   to prevent memory leaks. Additionally, if a component renders multiple
>   times (as they typically do), the **previous effect is cleaned up before
>   executing the next effect.**

```
// Return previous parent id and cache current
const oldParent = usePrevious(parent);

// Save scroll position when Component unmounts or parent id changes
useEffect(() => {
  if (oldParent && parent._id !== oldParent._id) {
    setScrollOffset(oldParent._id, list ? list.scrollTop : 0);
  }

  return () => {
    setScrollOffset(parent._id, scrollPos.current);
  };
}, [parent._id, oldParent]);
```

If this *does't* quite fit the bill, then use two effects, one for the mount/unmount and the other for just updates on the parent id.

Comment: This approach feels better when I look at it, but the problem I'm running into is that no matter what I do, the scrollPosition always comes up 0 if I do this approach.

Comment: @yourfavorite Can you get a codesandbox up? This is the gist, but if you could get a demo up I could tweak my solution.

Comment: Haha, I always have the hardest time boiling my code down to a sandbox. May take me a little time, but I'll work on it. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, just enough to create the two columns that can change their data, just the scenario you describe. And no worries. :)

Comment: Hey Drew. So I re-created my code on a sandbox and unfortunately it worked. Haha.  So I dug into my code more to see what might be causing the issue and it seems to be related to react-router (connected-react-router in my case). I ended up moving from useEffect to useLayoutEffect which fixed it.

Comment: Hi @yourfavorite, is it possible for you to share the codesandbox where you solved this problem? I have a similar issue, and it would be great if I could see a small working example. Thanks!

Comment: @Zachzhao I tried looking but it's been a while I'm. not sure where it is anymore. The best I can offer is the answer I posted to this question. Sorry.